# Cyanogenmod custom recovery can't backup, restore or apply an update!

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, twrp

I just installed Cyanogenmod. It's my understanding Cyanogenmod is a ROM so I was bit suprised when my TWRP custom recovery was replaced by Cyanogenmod's own recovery. Why is this?

Cyanogenmod's recovery can't do anything; it has no backup or restore options and each time I try to apply an update it says-

> signature verification failed.

1. Is it possible to get back to CWM or TWRP or somehow get Cyanogenmod's recovery to work?

I can't flash a new custom recovery from the phone since Cyanogenmod's recovery fails at flashing, and I tried using fastboot from the computer and it appears to flash TWRP but then it just goes by to Cyanogenmod's recovery.

2. I once read that TWRP/CWM only work with stock kernel and Cyanogenmod has it's own kernel so they won't work. Is this true?

I don't think it's relevant to the question but my phone is Xperia Z2 D6503 and the CM is 12 (Lollipop)

Comment: I have no idea about the answer to this, but, could you specify your device model and number? After all, you should know to do so, I mean, look at your reputation. Come on. 
By the way, CyanogenMod doesn't come with its own recovery. I have installed official builds of various devices, and it has shown no such replacement of the sort.

Comment: @rjt.rockx hmm device model/number are irrelevant. You don't understand the question. It's do they make custom recoveries so they need a specific kernel? and does Cyanogenmod count as a custom kernel (it has mod in it's name, people call it a ROM, so I don't know). You clearly don't know what your talking about as cyanogenmod does come with it's own recovery and that's the whole point of the question. You say you have never used it so why would you know?

Comment: @Celeritas :- There is this option in Developer Option menu that I must mention. While I do not understand the reason for such, in Cyanogenmod's Developer Menu, you might find an option like `Update CM Recovery`. As long as it remained checked, no matter how hard I tried I couldn't replace my recovery through fastboot. Fastboot showed me no error but rebooting the phone to recovery didn't booted into new one. I unchecked and it worked.

Comment: @Celeritas :- There is another thing that I never understood. I've OnePlus One and the first time when I tried to replace the recovery with fastboot, it didn't worked. No error in fastboot command but didn't booted into new one too. All I had to do was factory reset and after that it worked. I know it makes no sense that how could or why should be it working out this way but I thought I should convey my point here.

Comment: @Celeritas:- However, you didn't mention that whether you tried flashing TWRP/CWM recovery from inside the Android like through [Flashr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mkrtchyan.recoverytools&hl=en) app.

Comment: @Celeritas :- About this `I once red that TWRP/CWM only work with stock kernel and Cyanogenmod has it's own kernel so they won't work, is this true?` No it is not true. If you doubt my words then please consider heading over OnePlus forums [here](https://forums.oneplus.net/). Folks there run Stock Kernel that came with device and loaded with Cyanogenmod runs TWRP/CWM recovery. But those using other kernels like some AK Kernel also uses the said recoveries with no issues.

Comment: CM is virtually always used with a custom recovery.

Comment: @Celeritas , I have never said that I have never used CyanogenMod recoveries. I have flashed various builds of CyanogenMod (both official and unofficial) to many devices, and then I have installed a custom recovery (usually CWM or CWM-based) on top of it. I have had no such issues, so I mentioned that I have no idea about this topic. 
I know what I'm talking about. Please don't start an argument here. I don't wish to argue with you. If you don't want me to continue this conversation, then I don't see any reason to object against your decision.

Comment: What I meant to say was that whenever I installed a custom recovery, it would never get replaced again by CyanogenMod's own recovery. 

If it was with a specific device model and CyanogenMod version, then I could have tried to emulate the same thing and find out what the problem was, in order to find a correct solution. So, I asked for your device model and number. Hope you understand .

Comment: @rjt.rockx `What I meant to say was that whenever I installed a custom recovery, it would never get replaced again by CyanogenMod's own recovery` so you've successfully flashed a custom recovery after flashing CM? I can't do that. It's CM12 with Xperia Z2.

Comment: @MatthewRead in what sense do you mean that? I certainly had a good custom recovery before I flashed CM but then CM replaced it with its own crappy recovery.

Comment: @Celeritas , Yep, many times. CyanogenMod12 is doubtful, because I have only tried it out once, and it worked (on Micromax Canvas A1 (Android One - India)) I had the ThunderZap kernel and PhilZ touch recovery running on it, and it wasn't refusing the installation of a newer version of CWM recovery. I dunno about other devices, but it has always worked out fine for me.

Comment: I got it working. I used the app Rashr to install the custom recovery TWRP and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [xda thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=60672145&postcount=4): CyanogenMod recovery is basic, so you have to flash another one. The easiest way is to use [rashr app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mkrtchyan.recoverytools) and it worked for me perfectly

Comment: I tried this without success on Android 5.1. It said flashing is done, but it starts the Cyanogen Recovery after that again. Fashify (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.flashify&hl=en) worked for me, though.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are having this problem with a galaxy s2 and cyanogenmod 12.1, then the solution is to flash the original developers alternative stock kernel with TWRP installed. It is signed and thus can be flashed with the cyanogenmod recovery.

For details and further links see my answer on this question:
[How can I backup and restore Cyanogenmod 12.1 rom installed on my Samsung Galaxy 2 i9100?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119537/how-can-i-backup-and-restore-cyanogenmod-12-1-rom-installed-on-my-samsung-galaxy/132085#132085)

Answer (score 1):

Especially for Galaxy S2. I stuck with Cyanogen Recovery for a couple of days. Neither Rashr nor Flashify worked for me. In the end, reflashing a TWRP kernel (Apollo 9 light) with Flash Gordon did the trick.

Comment: for Galaxy S2 I9100,  recovery image with IsoRec support (like recent TWRP 3.0.2+) will allow you to keep using TWRP instead of CM Recovery - see https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxys2i9100.html. You need recent CM too (like cm-12.1-20160203-NIGHTLY-i9100.zip; cm-12.1-20151116-SNAPSHOT-YOG7DAO1JN-i9100.zip won't work as it lacks IsoRec support)