# How can I backup and restore Cyanogenmod 12.1 rom installed on my Samsung Galaxy 2 i9100?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, backup, restore, kernel

Cyanogenmod(12.1)'s recovery has no backup or restore option. As I read in the answer of a previous post, CyanogenMod recovery is basic, so we should flash another recovery. The easiest way would be to use rashr, Fashify or GooManager to install CWM or TWRP. Unfortunately, these solutions don't work on my i9100.

An other answer in the same post says : "Especially for Galaxy S2. I stuck with Cyanogen Recovery for a couple of days. Neither Rashr nor Flashify worked for me. In the end, reflashing a TWRP kernel (Apollo 9 light) with Flash Gordon did the trick."

My questions are where do I find this TWRP kernel and how do I install it ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a link to a signed stock kernel providing TWRP v2.8.7.0 on xda Forum : [ROM][I9100][5.1.1][OFFICIAL] CyanogenMod 12.1 Nightly Builds

It can be flashed with the Cynogen Recovery.

https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24052804347787517