# What's cyanogenmod's recovery.img?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I just went to download.cyanogenmod and saw the download now come with device-here-recovery.img. Can someone please tell me what is this for? thanks :)

Comment: Could you provide an example link? CyanogenMod is no recovery, so this confuses me. Usually, CM ships as flashable ZIP (to be flashed via the device's custom recovery) – but then it's not named `.img`.

Comment: CM has its own recovery now. https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2kgzfk/cm_is_going_to_use_own_cyanogen_recovery_ditches/

Comment: @Izzy See the fourth column here: https://download.cyanogenmod.org/

Comment: this recovery is mostly used in COS and not CM. (Cyanogen OS, not CyanogenMod). because COS, the system which is provided by Cyanogen Inc. on some mobile phones as stock ROM, this is the stock recovery on those phones. there is still the possibility of the cm recovery on every device which has got cm support, just because it's a stable recovery. it has not more features than other stock recoveries, I tried it myself. the only features are 1. flash signed updates (OTA, not any zip) 2. factory reset. not much more, but mostly useless tools.

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for the pointers! One more here at ASE: [Cyanogenmod custom recovery can't backup, restore or apply an update!](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/105051/16575) (the answer there fits the question here)

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a basic recovery that is available with CM ROMs. Due to CM nature of distribution, though, this doesn't mean that most CM ROMs will use it, but rather depends on the developer that is distributing it.